Using Excel Goal Seek to find maximum value when there are multiple correct answers
I am using Excel Goal Seek to calculate the maximum debt a set of cash flows can support to be repaid within a set period of time. The issue I am finding is that the Goal Seek will find a value (let's say $50 million), but if I manually increase the starting debt amount by say $500k, the project can still repay within that time period, meaning the debt sizing is not maximized. Essentially the final period has "excess cash flows" that are not being fully utilized when the debt is undersized.
I am wondering if there is a way for Goal Seek to find the maximum value when there are multiple answers?
Thanks
The issue I am finding is that the Goal Seek will find a value (let's say $50 million), but if I manually increase the starting debt amount by say $500k, the project can still repay within that time period, meaning the debt sizing is not maximized.

No, there is no way to do it in Goal Seek and it's probably the wrong tool for your problem. Your are a little scant on details but you can almost certainly to it with Excel's Solver.
